# Using WebMatrix.Data.Database.Open in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database

So after following:

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/webpages_database.asp

I'm trying to connect a database with my view as such:

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("SmallBakery");
    var selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM Product ORDER BY Name";    
}
```

I have referenced WebMatrix.Data and

```
var db = Database.Open("SmallBakery");
```

works in my model/controller but not in the view. When I do:

```
@var db = Database.Open("SmallBakery");
```

It's not finding the reference to WebMatrix.Data, only to System.Data.Entity.Database which does not contain the Open method. I'm not able to reference WebMatrix in my view either as such

```
@using WebMatrix.Data;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found out for some reason I need to copy WebMatrix.Data to \bin folder. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Asides from copying the WebMatrix.dll file to your bin folder.I tried that and it didn't work. You could also add a reference to WebMatrix at the beginning of the page where you want to use it. For example:

@using WebMatrix.Data;

then you can continue with your code, this worked for me after I installed WebMatrix.Data package via Nuget.